# How to extract point coordinates of lines from MGLShapeSource in Mapbox Swift

Tags: swift, mapbox

I plot lines correctly on a Mapbox iOS map using a geojson files I have created.
I read the geojson file and associate it to a shape like so:
`shapeFromGeoJSON = try? MGLShape(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)`

Then I create a linesSource and a linesLayer and then I show the linesLayer  on the map correctly:

`linesSource = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "polyline", shape: shapeFromGeoJSON, options: nil)`

`linesLayer = MGLLineStyleLayer(identifier: "polyline", source: linesSource)`

`mapView.style?.addSource(linesSource)`

`mapView.style?.addLayer(linesLayer)`

Inside the geojson file, each line is represented by a "geometry" with multiple "coordinates" of type "LineString".

I need to do some special processing that involves knowing all the coordinates of the points making the lines.

**Question**: how can I get all the multiple point coordinates of each LineString from linesSource?

Here's my geojson file for testing:

```
{
  "features": 

    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          -9.316333,
          38.680709
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "id": "1234"
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          [
            -9.31687,
            38.680772
          ],
          [
            -9.317531,
            38.679794
          ],
          [
            -9.318001,
            38.679196
          ],
          [
            -9.318436,
            38.678612
          ],
          [
            -9.318592,
            38.678354
          ]
        ],
        "type": "LineString"

      },
      "id": "567"
    },



    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          -9.316057,
          38.680838
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "id": "89"
    },



    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          -9.316719,
          38.680715
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "id": "1011"
    },




    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          -9.315931,
          38.681066
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "id": "1213"
    }
  ],
  "type": "FeatureCollection"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experiences with MapBox, not everything is easily user accessible. It might just be easiest to make a simple struct, decode the data into that, and access the coordinates from there.

Comment: Yes, that's what I just did and it works fine. Spend more time trying to find how to do it using mapbox APIs than coding the struct and decoding directly from the geojson file. Thanks!